# pySpark has a worker - driver version conflict when ran in Rodeo

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rodeo

The following simple script works fine in pyspark when it is ran from the terminal:

```
import pyspark

sc = pyspark.SparkContext()
foo = sc.parallelize([1,2])
foo.foreach(print)
```

But when ran in Rodeo, it produces an error, most important line of which says:

```
Exception: Python in worker has different version 2.7 than that in driver 3.5, PySpark cannot run with different minor versions
```

And the full error output can be found at this link: http://pastebin.com/raw/unGuGLhq

My`$SPARK_HOME/conf/spark-env.sh` file contains the following lines:

```
export PYSPARK_PYTHON=python3
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=python3
```

The problem persists despite that and putting the same lines in `~/.bashrc` doesn't solve the problem, either.

Rodeo version: 1.3.0

Spark version: 1.6.1

Platform: Linux

Comment: I have read the other question and it doesn't solve my problem, but your comment reminded me of an incredibly important info I forgot to include, thank you for that.

Comment: And you also set me on the right track to the solution, thank you again! The answer I submitted is similar to one of the answers offered in a question that mine was suspected of being a duplicate of, but the user that provided that answer did not specify where to put appropriate code.

Comment: I still don't get why it doesn't pick  these from `$SPARK_HOME/conf/spark-env.sh`. Strange...

Comment: I also don't fully understand that, I just paraphrased what I've found in the bug thread I linked there so I suppose these guys understand this issue better. All I understand is that desktop programs tend to operate using different environment variables than shell programs because they somehow don't exactly run as "my" threads... No idea what's this about, I'm a noob ;)

Comment: :) BTW, you should accept your own answer if it solved the issues.

Comment: Thanks for this remark! :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is related to one described here: [link](https://github.com/yhat/rodeo/issues/231)

Rodeo as a desktop app has a hard time working with shell environment variables. The trick is to put variables we'd normally declare in *spark-env.sh* in Rodeo's *.rodeoprofile* instead using **os** module to add them. Specifically in this case adding the following lines to *.rodeoprofile* helped:

```
os.environ["PYSPARK_PYTHON"]="python3"
os.environ["PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON"]="python3"
```

(though the second one is redundant and I added it just for consistence as the driver used 3.5 anyway)

Comment: I couldn't file .rodeoprofile file. Where is it located?